# Leer datos del LocalStorage sin refrescar página

Tags: angular, typescript

```js
openDialog() {
  const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ModalCouponsComponent);
  dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(data => {
    if (data) {
      this.leerLocalStorage()
    }

  });

}

leerLocalStorage() {
  if (!localStorage.getItem('cuponesArr')) {
    return;
  }
  const couponsAdd: Coupon[] = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cuponesArr'));
  this.cupArr = couponsAdd;

}
```

Obtengo un array de datos en una página (donde se almacena los datos) o dentro de un dialog, y se guarda en el localstorage. Lo que necesito es obtener los datos guardados en otra vista o página pero no al recargar o refrescar la página sino cuando se cierra el diálogo o modal. Estoy usando dialogo material de angular.

> me explicaron un poco de @Outpout, y Emmiter Gracias.

```js
// genero el array y guardo en el localstorage



agregar(coupon: Coupon) {
    if (this.addCoupons.some((p) => p === coupon)) return;
    this.addCoupons.push(coupon);
    this.guardarLocalStorage();
  
}
guardarLocalStorage() {
    localStorage.setItem('cuponesArr', JSON.stringify(this.addCoupons))
}

    // leo el localstorage pero lo hace cuando recargo la pagina alguna forma de leerlo al cerrar el dialogo

ngOnInit() {


    this.leerLocalStorage();
  }

  openDialog():void {
    this.dialog.open(ModalCouponsComponent);

  }

  leerLocalStorage() {
    if (!localStorage.getItem('cuponesArr')) {
      return;
  }
  const couponsAdd: Coupon[] = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cuponesArr'));
  this.cupArr = couponsAdd;
  
  }
```

```html
<div class="base_labels">
  <div class="labels_add" *ngFor="let item of cupArr; let i = index" (click)="DeleteTag(i)">
    <span class="label"
    >{{item.productName}}</span>
      
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes usar `afterClosed()` de Material Dialog, metes el .open del dialog a una constante de la que obtienes una Subscripcion:

```
openDialog() {
   const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ModalCouponsComponent);

   dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(data => { this.leerLocalStorage() });
 }
```

Comment: disculpa el close lo tengo en otro metodo donde lo cierro y quiero leer el local storage, serial la misma forma , ?   closeDialog() {
    this.dialogRef.close();
    this.leerLocalStorage();

  }

Comment: entiendo que eso afterclose indica que debe hacer el dialogo al cerrar el dialogo, que ese leer mi loclastorage, peor no lo esta haciendo, si retiro el llamado del onInit, no carga la data, no lo carga la data al cerrar el dialogo

Comment: Coloque en la parte superior como tengo el código ahora?

Comment: no tenia que poner el if, una consulta como puedo usar el atributo data que colocas, para que no quede sin usar?

Comment: Hola @SixtoMujica te invito a revisar una respuesta mas completa que ya di en este aspecto e los Dialogos de Material: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/529505/material-ui-dialog-insert-id-on-angular/530359#530359  alli muestro como comunicar la data dentro del .close(data)

Comment: Hola @Julio Daza Gracias por las sugerencias, una pregunta en lo que estoy implementando estoy haciendo un afterClosed, al cerrar el modal y ejecuto una carga de data al cerrar eso va bien cuando lo hago con el batón close, pero no logro lo mismo cuando cierno el modal con el fondo del dialog, parase que usa un metodo backdropClick(), pero no logro el mismo resultado, podrías sugerir como lo podría hacer. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Quiero lograr algo como esto lo mismo que hago con el afterclosed(), con el backdropClick(), paso los mismos valores pero no realiza la misma acción:

```js
openDialog() {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ModalCouponsComponent, {
      panelClass: 'modal-class-coupon',
      disableClose: false,
    });
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe( data => (this.validarCodigoDeRespuestaDeCuponesRedimidos(data.data)));

dialogRef.backdropClick().subscribe((data:any) => {
      // Close the dialog
      dialogRef.close((this.validarCodigoDeRespuestaDeCuponesRedimidos(data.data)));
    })
  }
```